# Ist »Hat es Ihnen geschmeckt?« rhetorisch?

Tags: sociolinguistics

Was soll *Hat es Ihnen geschmeckt?* bedeuten? Bisher habe ich nur beobachtet, dass man die Frage mit *Ja, sehr lecker* beantwortet und dass der Kellner den Teller abräumt.
Ich frage mich also, ob dies eine rhetorische Frage ist; eine Frage, deren einzige Antwort *Ja* sein darf? Oder kann man diese auch negativ beantworten (vorausgesetzt, man will wirklich meckern)?

Kann man etwa folgendes antworten?

> 1. Viel zu salzig.
> 2. Viel zu kalt.
> 3. Nicht lecker.

Comment: Ob der Verbreitung von "lecker" könnte man nun die Infantilisierung der deutschen Sprache beklagen. Muss man aber nicht.

Comment: Da ich das nun googeln musste: Für alle Normalsterblichen, mich eingeschlossen: @CarstenS möchte uns sagen, dass er "lecker" kindisch findet. Wenn es m.M.n. im Deutschen irgendetwas zu beklagen gibt, dann ist es die unnötige Verwendung von Beamtendeutsch. Lässt den Sprecher intellektueller wirken, trägt inhaltlich aber nichts bei. "Lecker" ist eine ausgezeichnete Wahl, wenn man aussagen möchte, dass das Essen geschmeckt hat.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

„Hat es Ihnen geschmeckt?“, oder auch „War’s recht?“, erscheint mir wie eine ganz normale Zielfrage. Mehrfach schon habe ich auch erlebt, wie der Gast erwiderte „Ja schon, aber …“ oder „Naja unter einer Fischsuppe verstehe ich etwas anderes …“ oder ähnliches.

Nur ist es eben so, dass eine solche Antwort eine unangenehme Atmosphäre hervorrufen kann, weshalb die meisten Restaurantbesucher lieber ein gelogenes „ja, war gut“ in das Gesicht der Bedienung lächeln, als Aufsehen zu erregen. Meines Erachtens nach macht diese weit verbreitete Reaktion die Frage aber keinesfalls zu einer rhetorischen.

Answer (score 12):

Meine Erfahrung ist, dass in guten Restaurants, wenige Minuten nachdem das Essen gebracht wurde, gefragt wird, ob das Essen schmeckt und/oder ob alles in Ordnung ist. An dieser Stelle ist eine ehrliche Antwort angebracht, denn noch kann die Küche eingreifen und ggf. nachbessern.

Wenn das Restaurant zu wenig Servicepersonal hat, wird diese Frage meist erst gestellt, wenn der Kellner den Tisch abräumt. Ich denke nicht, dass die Frage rhetorisch gemeint ist, aber ändern kann man ja dann auch nichts mehr. Wenn das Essen nun schlecht war, hätte ich mich schon viel früher ungefragt beschwert, war es mittelmäßig/OK, antworte ich mit *Es war in Ordnung*, wenn es gut war, antworte ich mit *Es war gut, danke*, und wenn es sehr gut war, mit *Es war sehr gut, danke. Ein Lob an die Küche!*.

Ich habe auch schon Leute kritisch antworten hören: *Ich habe (hier) schon besser gegessen.* Bei solchen kritischen Antworten frage ich mich dann aber immer, warum die Menschen sich nicht früher beschweren.

Comment: Ich ess sehr häufig im gleichen Restaurant. Dort schwankt die Qualität zuweilen ein bisschen. Wenn das Essen eher mäßig war, sage ich es dem Personal ebim Abräumen. Nur wenn ich gerne etwas anderes oder etwas nachgebessert hätte, sage ich es vorher. Das hat aber auch viel mit dem Preis zu tun: bei einem billigen Mittagessen toleriere ich recht viel, die Küche sollte daber dennoch erfahren, was die Gäste davon halten, denke ich.

Answer (score 2):

Die Definition einer rhetorischen Frage ist, wenn ich mich richtig an den Deutschunterricht erinnere, dass die Frage *überhaupt* keiner Antwort bedarf, weil von vornherein feststeht, was die Antwort ist, oder weil die Frage gar nicht direkt beantwortet werden kann, zum Beispiel wenn sie ein Redner im Parlament vorträgt.

> Da habe ich einen Fehler gemacht, *aber wer ist schon perfekt?*

Auf die Frage, ob es geschmeckt hat, erwartet der Kellner oder die Kellnerin aber in der Regel eine Antwort – sie wird direkt an eine Person gerichtet und eindeutig als Frage intoniert. (Die Perfektheitsfrage oben wird eher fallend, also als Aussagesatz intoniert.) Das schließt eine rhetorische Frage schon einmal aus, allerdings kann sie immer noch auf einer Ebene mit dem englischen »How are you?« stehen (dessen Antwort als »fine!« erwartet wird).

Dennoch bin ich der Meinung, dass eine (gerne verklausalierte, aber doch) ehrliche Antwort auf die Frage gegeben werden sollte. Nicht »viel zu salzig!«, das wäre zu direkt, allerdings wäre »Joar, war gut gewürzt« durchaus im Bereich des Möglichen.

Answer (score 0):

Kommt auf deine Definition von rhetorischer Frage an. Ich würde sagen, dass es sehr ähnlich der englischen Frage "How are you?" ist. Die erwartete Antwort steht bereits vorher fest und ist "I'm fine" / "Ja, sehr lecker".

Aber bei beiden Fragen kannst du natürlich auch eine - unerwartete - ehrliche Antwort geben. Wenn es nicht unessbar ist würde ich es aber immer diplomatischer ausdrücken als deine Vorschläge, zb:

- "Viel zu salzig" - > "War in Ordnung, aber etwas zu salzig für meinen Geschmack"
- "Nicht lecker" -> "War leider nicht so meins"

Für "viel zu kalt" wüsste ich keine nette Alternative, aber wenn mein Essen kalt ankommt würde ich das früher anmerken und ein neues verlangen oder einfach nichts sagen.

Comment: _Wie geht's?_ ist in Deutschland aber keine rhetorische Frage. Es gibt genug Deutsche, die ehrlich antworten mit _Nicht gut, aber muss ja/das Leben geht weiter_ oder ganz direkt mit _Beschissen._